# How to do static title and variable text to center of screen without shift title

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need to next structure on center of screen:

> Static title 1: some variable text
>
> Static title 2: some long variable text

Adding variable text should not displace the structure. How to do static position of title and don't move it during add new variable text? At the moment don't right, like this

[image]

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="lds-default">
        ... loader
    </div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Плейлист</td>
                <td id="lbl_title"></td>
            <tr>
                <td>Статус</td>
                <td id="lbl_message"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: is it required to display `Static title 1` and `Static title 2` in a table structure?

Comment: @csba No. Requires only location: title to the left, text to the right in one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if this works for you:

```
  .container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: left;
        -ms-flex-align: left;
            align-items: left;
  }
  .container .lds-default{
    -ms-flex-item-align: center;
        -ms-grid-row-align: center;
        align-self: center;
  }
```

Also, the first `<tr>` is not closed in your example.

Comment: If apply your style, the table location left of screen, loader by center

Comment: Sorry, I read your comment on the question and thought this is what you need. Could you give a more detailed explanation so that I can edit my answer?

Comment: I need to `loader` and `table` by center. At the same time adding text of different length-table title should not be shifted. The structure itself does not have to be in a table. It's just the only thing I can think of to put the title and text opposite each other.

Comment: So something like this? 
 `td{
   position: relative;
 }
 #lbl_title{
   position: absolute;
 }`

Comment: Yes! And some left shift for `table` to do center it

Comment: I think you can use something like `table{ margin-left: -100px; }` for that. But you will need another solution for responsive design....

Comment: Can you add a comment about `td` and `lbl_title` to the post?